# AVAudioConverter convert AVAudioPCMBuffer to AAC

Tags: swift, swift3, avfoundation, aac, avaudioconverter

I'm having an issue with `AVAudioConverter`. I'm trying to convert `AVAudioPCMBuffers` to `AAC`.

This is my function for converting, taken from the **"What's new in Core Audio"** **session 507** at **WWDC 2015**.

```
func convertPCMBufferToAAC(inBuffer : AVAudioPCMBuffer) -> Void {
    let inputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32,
                                    sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1,
                                    interleaved: false)

    var outDesc = AudioStreamBasicDescription(mSampleRate: 8000,
                                              mFormatID: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
                                              mFormatFlags: 0,
                                              mBytesPerPacket: 0,
                                              mFramesPerPacket: 0,
                                              mBytesPerFrame: 0,
                                              mChannelsPerFrame: 1,
                                              mBitsPerChannel: 0,
                                              mReserved: 0)

    let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &outDesc)
    let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat)
    let outBuffer = AVAudioCompressedBuffer(format: outputFormat,
                                            packetCapacity: 8,
                                            maximumPacketSize: converter.maximumOutputPacketSize)

    let inputBlock : AVAudioConverterInputBlock = {
        inNumPackets, outStatus in
        outStatus.pointee = AVAudioConverterInputStatus.haveData
        return inBuffer
    }
    var error : NSError?
    let status = converter.convert(to: outBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputBlock)
}
```

The problem is that the outBuffer is empty. If I print it I get the output `<AVAudioCompressedBuffer@0x170012420: 0/6144 bytes>` so as you can see it is not filled.

If your wondering I'm getting the `AVAudioPCMBuffer` from installing a tap on the `AVAudioEngine`. This I'm converting to the same format as `inputFormat` using the `AVAudioEngines` main mixer.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `inputFormat` you construct differs from `inBuffer.format`. Try this instead:

```
let inputFormat = inBuffer.format
```

and make sure to run the code on a device, as it does not appear to work on the simulator.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, same problem and error code (Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)") as before :/

Comment: Is your inputBlock being called?

Comment: Nope it is not.

Comment: What version of iOS is your device running?

Comment: That's really strange. `AVAudioConverter` seems broken in iOS 10. There was a change (bug?) in uncompressed conversions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39779017/22147 but the workaround doesn't seem to help here. Can you open a TSI with Apple?

Comment: Yes saw that thread as well. I opened a similar thread on Apples developer forums, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67106?q=avaudioconverter and it's apparently a known issue.

Comment: ouch. I can confirm that `AVAssetWriter` with `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` works flawlessly on iOS10.

Comment: I see, good to know! But I need to convert in real time though. I ended up choosing the LAME framework to convert it to mp3 for now.

Comment: lame is great!!